# Typescript: return a value depends on generic type

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

I need to make this logic work.

```
const defaultNumberOption = {
  label: 'Select',
  value: 0,
};

const defaultStringOption = {
  label: 'Select',
  value: '',
};

const getDefaultOption = <ValueType extends string | number>(): IOption => {
  // if ValueType is 'string' - return defaultStringOption 
  // if ValueType is 'number' - return defaultNumberOption 
}
```

I tried to use different approaches, but with each of them had the same problem: I can't find a way to make a structure with types in condition, but with values in expression.

If there is a way to do it - it would be great.

Comment: In the getDefaultOption function, would you be passing in a parameter? Like `const getDefaultOption = <ValueType extends string | number>(value: ValueType): IOption`?

Comment: Because I think there may not be a way to check what's the concrete type of the Generic declaration since it's defined as either string or number. But we can check the type of a variable using `typeof`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to achieve this.

```
interface DefaultNumberOption {
    label: 'Select',
    value: number,
}

interface DefaultStringOption {
    label: 'Select',
    value: string,
}

type DefaultOption<T extends number | string> = T extends string
    ? DefaultStringOption
    : DefaultNumberOption

const getDefaultOption = <T extends number | string>(value: T): DefaultOption<T> => {
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
        return {
            label: 'Select',
            value: ''
        } as DefaultOption<T>;
    }
    return {
        label: 'Select',
        value: 0
    } as DefaultOption<T>;
}

let x = getDefaultOption(''); // x will have type DefaultStringOption
let y = getDefaultOption(0); // y will have type DefaultNumberOption
```

Here is a link to a [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIXgVwDZgHKYC2ARtAPIAOYwA9iMgN4CwAUMu8tnKdgFzIByAMoRsEBGAEAaVh2QA3ONkwR+IIqSgyWAX1atQkWIhTosuIWCigA5pWp1Gsjlx79ho8ZO1zFy1cgAzla22nosrGAAnhSmGHA4YPa0IAA8ACrIEAAekCAAJoHI6iTQyAA+QSEgNgB8yAC8yJk5eYVV1jXO7AD8aPGJlp12VCndyPxmCbgEpVDJdPosCHTByDYQYFOJC-RNGVm5EAVFJZoVHba1ABR+KvzpAJSTA7i7GfUN9cxsHMAwyGu0ViNABdxQDUhgmCwwEjycvzk7Cgm0wUHoPyRWM43FE7hEYgk0nG2IUSnuggEJI4OmQcCK2zeozoHwA3ONwnIUWA0RjqexXHjBASvMTEUjwfwAAwcukM15JZlpdK1dm6JZiMDIbKNdabRmKhwga4COFqzXIKK6jZbBW7a5Sx6soA) if you want to play around with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
enum FixedLabel {Select}

const defaultNumberOption = {
 label:  FixedLabel.Select,
 value: 0,
};

const defaultStringOption = {
   label:  FixedLabel.Select,
   value: '',
};
type DefaultNumber = { label: FixedLabel, value: number};
type DefaultString = { label: FixedLabel, value: string};
type IOption = DefaultNumber | DefaultString;

const getDefaultOption = (v : number | string): IOption => {
 // if ValueType is 'string' - return defaultStringOption 
 // if ValueType is 'number' - return defaultNumberOption 
 if(typeof v === 'string'){
     return defaultNumberOption;
  } else {
   return defaultStringOption;
 }  
}
```

You can try this might work for you can also use string instead of enum if you are not sepcific to labels.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript loses the typing information provided in `<T extends string | number>` when building to JS, which is why it does not allow you to use that.

In order to obtain the type, you may want to provide it as a parameter in the function.

```
const getDefaultOption = <T extends string | number>(optionValue: T): IOption => {
    return typeof optionValue === "string" ? defaultStringOption : defaultNumberOption;
}
```

It is also possible to add it to the return type instead:

```
const getDefaultOption = <T extends string | number>(getOptionType: T): IOption<string | number> => {
    if (typeof getOptionType === "string") return defaultStringOption;
    else return defaultNumberOption;
}
```

Note that IOption cannot contain `<T>` as TS would require the return type to be `string | number` instead of `string` or `number`.

Here's [my TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkg8mYBLA9gOwDwBUoQB7ARoAmAzlKcAE5JoDmUAPlGgK4C2ARhFQHxQBeKAG8AUFCgAbAIbdJALgrVadADTioAN2mTWERVlEBfUaIDG6SlGIQAZtNaTgAOQ7cqCZOkXxEqTGxcPPxCYhIycooA5ADKEJIQZsBR6hLauvpQAAzqRgDcphZoVjb2jsAxyvSe-j416BiUNPQhIhoR8dFxCUkpGul60X35hZbAUHQQwAAidg5O9WiCUNi4BERkSs0MzIHuvAAUk8CLWOCZWACUdX4NTSpMLG7BgvxhUEi2UAegkChfx1O50EAiEACJ7vQwZcoFQpqwqEtSvMKlU6IsChJ4qRoHDgAikXNyq4gh5bmgCkYgA)